# How do i overflow to the left and to the top?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I'm working on a sort of editor with drag and drop functionality.

So my overflow is working correctly when i'm dragging my element to the bottom of the screen or to the right of the screen.

When i drag it to the left or to the top of the screen it does nothing. Which is the logical flow of a web page. But is it possible to overflow to the left and top the same way as it does to the right and bottom?

Screenshots with correct overflow, here you can see the scrollbars are added when going outside of the outer element:
 [image: bottom overflow]

[image: right overflow]

Screenshots with incorrect overflow, here you can see that nothing is added:

[image: top overflow]

[image: left overflow]

My code is nothing special. My outer element has `overflow:auto` and for the overflow-y i have to do `event.srcElement.scrollTop = 0;` to not scroll to bottom with the element but stay at top so that whitespace is created.